# Resistor and heat

Tags: circuit-analysis

Due to a power supplier manufacturer chanege the BOM lately, it require now more current to be drawn (need more load on my circutry side). I added a resistor in order to draw more current from the power supply, but the problem is the resistor is dissipating a lot of heat. Othter than adding a resistor to the circuitry, is there any other way to make my board draw more current from the power supply?

Comment: How much more current do you need to draw? What is the voltage? And roughly how much heat do you mind generating?

Answer (score 4):

A more sophisticated solution is an active dummy load, which combines some sort of load (like a resistor or a MOSFET) with a current sensing element, only turning on the dummy load when needed. Once the rest of your system is drawing sufficient current, the dummy load can turn off saving it from generating heat all the time.

If your load is *always* below the minimum specified current for the power supply, you really should consider a different power supply - you're paying for power that you'll never use.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with a power supply that outputs a constant voltage, if you increase the current, you also increase the power that is drawn from the power supply.

$$ P=U I $$

And according to the energy conservation law, this excess of power has to be converted. It could be into heat, light, RF, movement, etc...

If your circuit has to output the same but has to consume more, it has to dissipate the difference. And heating seems the easiest way to go. So what you did is correct. It is heating, and it's good because it's exactly what we want: dissipate energy into heat.

Resistors are not the only thing that can be used. Power MOSFETS works too. But in all case, make sure you are within the absolute maximum rating of the chosen parts.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever current you draw, the energy contained in that current will need to be converted into some other kind of energy. Your resistor, and most of the other devices in your circuit will be converting that energy almost entirely into heat.

If you draw more current, you're almost certainly going to have to convert that into heat, but you have a couple of options:

1. Spread the heat around so that it's not a big problem:

Use a high power resistor with a screw tab to attach it to a heatsink. You could screw this to the metal casing of your device if it has one. This won't reduce the total amount 
of *heat* generated, but it will spread it around so that the resultant *temperature* isn't so high.

[image: TO220 resistor]

2. Convert some of the energy into something other than heat.

This is a little trickier, since almost all other forms of energy will eventually become heat. You might try using a DC fan instead instead of a resistor.

[image: DC fan]

Strictly speaking, since this is adding kinetic energy to the air, it's actually producing heat, but it may be better than a resistor in some cases because:

- You could just blow the air out of the casing, taking much of the energy with it.
- You could use that moving air to cool down the rest of the circuit, thus compensating for the extra heat created.

One more option is to convert the energy into something else, like light. Use a high power LED, and shine the energy out of the device.

[image: High power LED]

This will actually generate less heat than the resistor, as long as you let the light escape the device. However, it won't make that much difference. If I remember correctly, LEDs are still only about 10% efficient, so it would still produce about 90% as much heat
as the resistor.

---

OK, but here's the killer way to solve your problem. What you want is some kind LED which is more than 80% efficient, so that it produces way less heat, allowing you to shine your excess energy far from your device. Well, here it is, an LED which is [*more than 100% efficient!*](http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2012-03/09/230-percent-efficient-leds) Actually it's 230% efficient. Well, that's only true if you're looking at it from an electrical perspective. If the article is to be believed, the LED actually gets cold as it works, taking in heat energy from the environment.

Comment: Personally, I think that 230% efficient LED sounds unlikely. Getting colder than the surrounding is the *opposite* of extracting energy from the environment, because that temperature difference itself could be harvested and converted into other forms of energy.

Answer (score 0):

What could possibly be done with the unneeded energy beside convert it to heat?  Convert it to light, sound, or mechanical motion.  Instead of a resistor, use LEDs or other light sources (with appropriate current limiting methods), or an audio amplifier - do you want the thing to be noisy?   Running a fan, as others suggest, seems fine, if air cooling would be helpful.  Another option is to emit radio waves - could you use up power sending out a hefty bluetooth/wi-fi signal, if it would have any relevance to the product?